# Spring RequestMapping not working as expected

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, servlets

I have a problem understanding RequestMapping in Spring, as it doesn't work as I expect.
What I'm trying to do is mapping "/" to return "registration.jsp", and than showing the user a form to fill and returning a "greeting.jsp" page. This is my code, but what I'm getting when I launch my webapp is / showing the Registration jsp, when i fill the data it gets inside the controller method mapping / with "registration" (i expect it to be happened before display the registration page, isn't it right?), and after i click submit the action isn't caught by the controller method handling the greeting page. This is my code....

Controller:

```
package org.fabrizio.lastfmmusicrecommender.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;
@Controller
public class LastFmController {

@RequestMapping("/")
public String showRegistration(){
    return "RegistrazioneUtente";
}

@RequestMapping(value="/registrazioneAction", method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String registraUtente(){
    return "greetings";
}
}
```

My registration jsp:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
  <title>Registrazione Utente</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Registrazione Utente</h2>
  <form role="form"  action="/registrazioneAction" method="get">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="username">Username:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="username" placeholder="Enter email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="password">Password:</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Enter password">
    </div>
    <div class="checkbox">
      <label><input type="checkbox"> Utente Last.fm?</label>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app id="WebApp_ID" version="2.4"
    xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/j2ee/web-app_2_4.xsd">
    <display-name>LastFmCarMusicRecommender</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>/index.jsp</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
    <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet</servlet-class>
    <init-param>
<param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
<param-value>/WEB-INF/config/spring-context.xml</param-value>
</init-param>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>springmvc</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

springmvc-servlet.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans

http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-4.0.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context 
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-4.0.xsd">

 <context:component-scan base-package="org.fabrizio.lastfmmusicrecommender.controller" />

    <bean id="viewResolver"
        class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.UrlBasedViewResolver">
        <property name="viewClass"
            value="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView" />
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>


</beans>
```

So basically when I start the web-app, it doesn't go in the controller ("/") requestmapping but correctly shows the registration form, as I fill the data it goes inside that method (how des it display the right page if it scans the controller code AFTER displaying the page?), but it doesn't go inside the method I called in the form action. What I get instead in the log is:

```
    02/02/2015 11:07:43 - DEBUG - (InternalResourceView.java:170) - Forwarding to resource [/WEB-INF/views/RegistrazioneUtente.jsp] in InternalResourceView 'RegistrazioneUtente'
02/02/2015 11:07:44 - DEBUG - (FrameworkServlet.java:996) - Successfully completed request
```

Thanks for the suggestion, I tried to explain and attach as much useful stuff I could.

EDIT: this is spring-context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans:beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:beans="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:mvc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc"
    xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc http://www.springframework.org/schema/mvc/spring-mvc.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context.xsd">

    <!-- DispatcherServlet Context: defines this servlet's request-processing infrastructure -->

    <!-- Enables the Spring MVC @Controller programming model -->
    <annotation-driven />

    <!-- Handles HTTP GET requests for /resources/** by efficiently serving up static resources in the ${webappRoot}/resources directory -->
    <resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />

    <!-- Resolves views selected for rendering by @Controllers to .jsp resources in the /WEB-INF/views directory -->
    <beans:bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <beans:property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <beans:property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </beans:bean>

    <context:component-scan base-package="org.fabrizio.lastfmmusicrecommender.controller" />
        <mvc:resources mapping="/resources/**" location="/resources/" />


</beans:beans>
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem i saw is this:-

```
@RequestMapping(value="/registrazioneAction", method=RequestMethod.POST)
```

the mapping is for post request but the form has get

```
<form role="form"  action="/registrazioneAction" method="get">
```

change method from "get" to "post" hope it solves the problem

Comment: I did it just to test and forgot to edit it back, I already tried that... Indagating a little bit more the registration form is shown with URL "/" instead of registrationPage, and now i get a 404 on /registrazioneAction.

Comment: Hi do you have <annotation-driven /> in the xml

Comment: yes, i edited the main post to show spring context xml.

Comment: Hey buddy i dont know if it will work but try this                                    <form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/registrazioneAction" method="post">

Answer (score 0):

user3829082 was faster with the same answer (mostly line by line ;) )

Additional: I cannot explain why you don't see any progress in your root mapping ("/"). It seems correct to me and it also does render the right view.

Comment: It DOES show the right view, but i get in the controller method AFTER the page is displayed. And when i click on submit i get a 404 on the "registrazioneAction" that has no page but is mapped under requestmapping.

Comment: Just to understand you right: 1. HTML and java code is mapped to do a post request (your comment in the other answer) 2. What do you mean with *after* the page is displayed? This is a simple request <> response thing. if no async calls occur this code has to be executed when you do the first request (throw a runtime exception in the first mapped method to be sure). 3. I seems that you know it, but don't try to call the registrazioneAction by browser url it will do a get.

Comment: The compiler doesn't pass through breakpoint in the controller mapping / to registerUser page, but the view is displayed correctly. When i click on the submit button the mapping method with the name of the action is not called and I get a 404.

Comment: Your breakpoint is on the return statement, right? It won't work on the annotation. Is there any log message if the 404 occurs?